# Youtube/facebook videos randomly get glitchy and pixelated in the start or in the middle of a video

Tags: video, graphics-card, youtube, lag

It either happens in the middle of a video, like you seen in the picture here: [image: http://imgur.com/a/H5rhP]
or in the few first seconds of a video.

As you can see from the picture (and you can try to open my example yourself), it's not the problem from the video. My uneducated guess is there is a problem with my GPU. But I am not sure. I asked around on Reddit, and got told to turn off hardware acceleration but that didn't work.

I have a GTX 1070, and it's up-to-date and the problem mostly only come from playing YouTube videos. I don't recall having this with media players (Windows Media Player or VLC) or image-editing/video-editing software like Photoshop or Sony Vegas or with any games either.

This issue came out of the blue..
Does anyone know how to fix this? Getting worried my gpu might be damaged :(

*I also feel like its getting worse and worse everyday with the problem occurring more frequently.*

Comment: Which browser? Chrome? Have you tried other browsers? Have you tried switching between flash/pepperflash/HTML5?

Comment: What CPU do you have? What temperatures is it experiencing at rest and during YouTube video streaming? What happens if you reinstall your browser?

Comment: Try updating the web-based video accelerator software, I think it will help, or simply reinstall the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the exact same thing as well as having a GTX 1070. So I was worried about this being a problem too. I've been testing out the videos on Edge (Internet Explorer) and I didn't get any piexlation. Talking to my friends they've said it's chrome having an issue with the most recent flash update. So there is chance your facebook videos/gifs are getting piexlated too (Which they were for me)

TL:DR - Chrome is the problem (If that's the browser you're using) since the newest flash update, I think.